# Difficulties running plugin sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I try to install sbt-assembly to create jar file with all my scala files and their dependencies.

I already installed sbt (the command "sbt sbt-version" in shell gives the following version: 0.13.9). I downloaded sbt-assembly from the Github repository (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and extracted in a folder.

I followed the instruction in the README on Github (creating a /project/assembly.sbt file with "addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")" inside). I also created a /project/build.sbt file, following this tutorial (http://raintomorrow.cc/post/50811498259/how-to-package-a-scala-project-into-an).

Anyway, when I write the command "sbt run" or "sbt assembly" in the shell (I am located in the folder where the sbt-assembly files are), I always get two errors message saying that the object "import AssemblyKeys._" and the value "assemblySettings" (from the file /project/build.sbt I just created) are not found.

If someone knows what I am doing wrong, it would be very helpful.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`build.sbt` should be in the root of your project, not in `project/build.sbt` (but files adding SBT plugins *should* be in `project`). You should also be running `sbt ...` commands from the root. Also, `AssemblyKeys` and `assemblySettings` [should be removed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/Migration.md), they are only used with older `sbt-assembly` versions.

Comment: Even if I put the build.sbt file in the root of my project, I still get the two error messages about "import AssemblyKeys._" and "assemblySettings" not known.

Comment: See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/Migration.md, they should be removed.